# How to access a View Struct in other View struct in swiftui

Tags: view, swiftui

In one view, I have this func to signUp and get userName

```
func signUp() {
 
    if self.email != "" {
        if self.password == self.repass {
    session.signUp(email: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
        
        if error != nil {
            self.error = error!.localizedDescription
            //self.error = "A senha deve ter 6 caracteres ou mais"
        }
            else{
                self.email = ""
                self.password = ""
                
                let db = Firestore.firestore()
                db.collection("Users").document(result!.user.uid).setData(["userName": userName]) { (error) in
                    if error != nil{
                    
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
        else{
            self.error = "Senhas não coincidem"
        }
}
    else{
        self.error = "Complete todos espaços"
}
}
```

In other view, I want to get the userName the user typed ad display it, but for this I need to link both views to get access to func SignUp. How to do it?

**EDIT:**

Based on the answer I was given, I did the corresponding changes:

SessionStore:

```
@Published var session: User? = nil
var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
@Published var userName: String = ""




func listen() {
    
    handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ [self] (auth, user) in
        if let user = user {
            self.session = User(uid: user.uid, email: user.email!, userName: userName)
        }
        else {
            self.session = nil
        }
    })
}




struct User {

var uid:String
var email:String
var userName: String

}
```

HomeView ----> `var userName: User`

```
Text(userName.userName)
```

- explaining how my code works: the `@main` view is `MedAppApp: App`. From there, the code goes to `ContentView`. if `session.session != nil`, `TransitionView`, else, `SignView`. Continuing from `SignView`, there I have both `SignInView` and `SignUpView` views, which they have `Button(action: signIn)` and `Button(action: Signup)`, respectively. Continuing from `TransitionView`, there is where I have:

  ```
   struct TransitionView: View {
   @StateObject var LocationModel = LocationViewModel()
   @State var userName = User(uid: "", email: "", userName: "")

   var body: some View {
       HomeView(LocationModel: LocationModel, userName: userName)
   }
  }
  ```
- `@State var userName =...`   and  `userName: userName` needed to be added

The app launches, I can signUp with username (and its stored in Firestore with uid as document), but the userName isn't displayed. I think the problem must be in User(uid: "", email: "", password: ""). I didn't know what to add there.

By the way, Im thinking about maintaining the code and then get the userName by using the document id (that already is the user uid) so I can access it. Don't have a final answer yet, but Im working on it.

**EDIT2:**
I added @StateObject var session = SessionStore()

Tried to use:

```
@State var userName = User(uid: SessionStore().session?.uid ?? "", email: SessionStore().session?.email ?? "", userName: SessionStore().session?.userName ?? "")
```

Still doesn't work

Comment: "but for this I need to link both views" - that's not how SwiftUI works. Instead, update some view model (an ObservableObject) when you get the user name. Then, design the views to update based on this value with a conditional, e.g. `if let userName = vm.userName { ContentView() }`

Comment: Hey @NewDeve, thanks for replying. I didn't quite understand what you are saying, Im kinda new to SwiftUI

Comment: @NewDev I asked another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64859475/how-to-get-information-from-a-func-in-a-view-struct-swiftui-firebaseauth (I added more code to perhaps facilitate understanding). Try answering there so I can delete this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is too open-ended, but I'll provide an answer that hopefully will set you up on the right direction.

First, in SwiftUI, separate the concept of a view (i.e. how things are arranged on the screen) from the concept of data that drives the views. What I mean by that is, if you need some data, like `userName`, the code that obtains it shouldn't know or care about which view will make use of it. And Views, shouldn't care how the data is obtained.

Second, in SwiftUI, views should not be thought of as "entities" (like in UIKit) with their own life cycles. They are just declarative statements that define how the UI is arranged.

For example, suppose you have this (fake) `class` that signs the user in, and when signed-in, populates the `userName` property. The instance of this class is a view model.

```
struct User {
   let userName: String
}

class Session: ObservableObject {
   @Published var user: User? = nil

   func signIn(_ completion: (User) -> ()) {
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(.now() + 0.5) {
         self.user = User(userName: "Mateus") // fake sign-in
         completion(self.user) // not really used in this example
      }
   }
}
```

<sup>`@Published` and `ObservableObject` in combination are how SwiftUI views know to react to changes to this object. Read more about them, if you don't know what they do.</sup>

Next, design a root view that decides what inner view to display depending on whether the user is signed in or not:

```
struct RootView: View {
   @StateObject var session = Session()

   var body: some View {
      VStack() {
         if let user = session.user { 
            ContentView(user: user)  // view is conditionally rendered
         } else {
            Button("sign in") { self.signIn() }
         }
      }
   }

   func signIn() {
      self.session.signIn() {
         print("signed in...!")
      }
   }
}
```

<sup>`@StateObject` manages the life cycle of the view model for the view.</sup>

As you see above, `ContentView` will only be rendered when `session.user` is not `nil` (i.e. when user has signed in), so the view is driven by changes in data. I did not need to create a `ContentView` instance anywhere ahead of time.

Then `ContentView` is straightforward:

```
struct ContentView: View {
   var user: User

   var body: some View {
      Text("signed-in username: \(user.userName)")
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying again, I just updated my question

Comment: @MateusNevesdeoliveira, your update introduces more issues beyond the original scope. Feel free to ask new questions. With this answer I was just trying to give you a general direction

Comment: No problem. Just a quick question: in your code you used ContentView(user: user) because you had "@"StateObject var session = Session() and "@"Published var user: User? = nil, right? Why  doesn't  HomeView(userName: userName) work in my code, as in TransitionView I have "@"StateObject var session = SessionStore() and "@"Published var userName:Strong = "" ?

Comment: I'm not fully following what's going on in your code, so hard to say